# Kmeans clustering data storage/plotting

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the output of the clustering into a dataframe for visualization. This is a conceptual question, but please let me know if you need the dataset. I think it can be answered without it.

```
cluster_result <- kmeans(df,centers=3)

data <- data.frame( df, cluster = cluster_results$cluster)
```

The following when plotted does not display clustered data!

Comment: could you provide your plotting code

Comment: How many columns does `df` have?

Comment: I am not sure of what exactly you mean by "does not display clustered data". Binding the cluster allocation as a new column in a data frame make sense if you are plotting the original data and using the cluster allocation to colouring them differently, for example... But you will see a clear cluster in any two or tridimensional plot just if the data can really be described by a very low number (two or three) of variables... frequently we would like to capture a little more complexity than that when we are applying cluster analysis...

Comment: All: the output will written onto a csv for Tableau visualization. @hamagust So you're saying that: "The approach is correct, and the "data" has been grouped by cluster? Could one just do a scatter plot directly from that step? I was thinking more needs to be done with coordinates!

Comment: @Achiles. The code above should provide the cluster allocation. Yes. The approach in this sense, is correct. The cluster analysis provide groups. But a simple scatter plot? Not necessarily... If the data used for the cluster analysis have 2 or 3 variables, certainly simple scatter plot will show the groups clearly... But if you have more variables, possibly the scatter plot will not be so illustrative at all... but depends on your data... it is usual to add scatter plot of all pair of variables, but just as complementary analysis... not as the main plot showing the results...

Comment: also: you have added cluster_results$cluster, but your object is cluster_result without "s"...